# Wordpress uploads folders giving 404 errors - still happening

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, google-search-console

I'm checking our webmaster tools account again and some of our wp-content/uploads folders are showing up as 404 errors. i.e…

```
http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/
http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/
http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/
```

The folders don't have anything in them except the uploaded images (no blank html file etc) and the file paths to the images in those folders are working fine. Obviously I don't want to block crawl access to the folders as quite a few of our images are being indexed in google image search.

Any idea why the paths to these folders would be giving a 404 error?

Answer (score 0):

Check the permission settings for the upload directory, if they are aren't either 755 or 750 then
check out the Wordpress docs [Changing File Permissions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)

Comment: They're all set to 755

Comment: This problem is still happening - What is causing this?

Comment: yeah I'm getting the same

Comment: Likely to be an issue with the apache conf then blocking and not allowing these folders to be indexed.